# Generate iPhone UIButton from parsed xml file

Tags: iphone, xml, dynamic, uibutton

I have been able to NSXML parse an xml file from my server which loads a series of images and titles into a `ScrollView`...

But I can't find any reference of how to dynamically generate and position several `UIButtons` (or Alerts) on one of the `UIViews`.

Some of the images will need hotspots which when pressed opens an alert view with reference text.

Is it possible to create UIButtons from a parsed xml document? Thought I'd ask before spending any more time on chasing rainbows :)

Of course any pointers or URLs would be a bonus.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `UIButton` the same way you create any other ui elements:

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 12.0f, 12.0, 50.0f, 30.0f)];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPreseed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubView:button];
[button release], button = nil;
```

Comment: Thanks rckoenes, I know how to add a button programmatically and how to structure my xml file. I think my real issue is that I need to learn (and understand) xml parsing better. Then I can create variables to generate the button (position) and populate the alert box in buttonPressed.